# How to install FileZilla on CentOS?

Tags: centos, software-installation, filezilla

I downloaded *FileZilla* from [here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php.) Now how to install this on CentOS?

I used `yum install filezilla` but it is showing errors like:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error message explians the problem:

> ```
> You need to be root to perform this command.
> ```

In *nix when you have to install something, you need to have the permissions to install it. The *root* account is a special account which is like the *Administrator* account in windows. So for installing anything, you need to be root.

So first login into the *root* account, or use `sudo`:

```
sudo yum install filezilla
```

If your account does not allow sudo, then you will have to login into root:

```
su root -
yum install filezilla
```

You do not need to download it first, `yum` will download it automatically.

What you have downloaded is the *source code* of Filezilla. It is used for installing  Filezilla manually. It is much harder to install it like this, and you should use yum instead.

Comment: I tried ` sudo yum install filezilla ` but showing error  mpatil is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: It means your account does not have the necessary permissions. Are you the Admin?

Comment: ya am the admin

Comment: Do you have password of the Root account?

Comment: ya have password

Comment: So try to login into the root account, and try to install (without sudo) there.

Comment: how to login to root account?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11208/discussion-between-kartik-and-user2854207)

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login as root, do yum installl filezilla, press Ctrl+D to logout, Ctrl+Alt+F7 or F-something to go back.